# Converting a split dataframe into csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have to split a dataframe containing 15000 rows into sections of 300 rows each.

```
split_df = np.array_split(data, np.arange(0, len(data),300))
```

I need to convert the split groups into a dataframe/dataframes and then to be converted to a csv.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have one idea.

```
split_df = np.array_split(data, np.arange(0, len(data),300))
for i in range(len(split_df)):
  csv_writer = split_df[i].to_csv('data'+str(i)+'.csv')
```

You can use this code to output everything as a csv
I hope it fits what you want to do.
The only thing is that this code will take some time to finish running.
Please be aware of that.

Comment: Thank you. It worked fine and didn't take time at all.